# Installing Ubuntu on android device (HTC Desire HD)

Tags: htc

I want to install Ubuntu on my Android device. Details of my handset as below;

`HTC Desire HD - A9191 | 768 MB RAM | Chipset   - Qualcomm MSM8255 Snapdragon | CPU - 1 GHz Scorpion | GPU  - Adreno 205`

Where can I find and install Ubuntu OS for my HTC desire HD? Please advise.

Comment: Your heading says that you need `Ubuntu one` & at the end of your question you mentioned `"Ubuntu OS"`. Exactly which one are you referring to??

Answer (score 0):

**Google: "Install Ubuntu on HTC"** returned **About 3,760,000 results (0.20 seconds)**
The first of which is

```
Touch/Devices - Ubuntu Wiki
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Devices‎
Aug 26, 2013 - HTC Desire Z (use --wipe with phablet-flash or boot will most likely fail!)
vision, flipped containers ... Unlocking instructions. Install instructions.
```

Did you check [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Devices)?